# Blazor - Navigate to Id after page renders

Tags: javascript, blazor

Framework: .Net6.0

C#: 10.0

How do I navigate to an Id after the page finishes rendering? I have a virtualized list of items, one item out of the list gets assigned an Id.

I want to be able to scroll down to this Id after the page finishes rendering.

I'm able to scroll down 'manually' simply by adding '#IdName' to the end of the url. I'm unable to get blazor to scroll down to this Id using the Navigation Manager.

I've tried the following in `OnAfterRenderAsync`:

```
 _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/test#testscroll");
```

and the following JS and C# code in `OnAfterRenderAsync`

```
await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToElementId", "");
```

Javascript

```
scrollToElementId = (elementId) => {
    elementId = "testscroll";
    console.info('scrolling to element', elementId);
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(!element)
    {
        console.warn('element was not found', elementId);
        return false;
    }
    element.scrollIntoView();
    return true;
}
```

The JS file has been added to wwwroot/Javascript/main.js

and

```
<script src="Javascript/main.js"></script>
```

added above

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

in `_Layout.cshtml`

The JS listed above DOES work, but only for items that are not in the virtualized list. If I add a static div to the bottom of the list, out side the Virtualize tag, it will scroll to the bottom. But if I try to use a Id from and item inside the Virtualize tag, it does not scroll.

I receive the `element was not found` console warning from the JS, when using Id's from the virtualized list.

Comment: The Id's are not in the web page that is the point of virtualization. The best you can do is run a query to find the offset of the desired row and use that.

Comment: You can't scroll to an item in a virtual list because it doesn't exist in the html.  It's virtual until you physically scroll the item into view.  That's probably why you get the `element was not found`.  Virtual lists have their drawbacks.  I use them, but not as often as I thought I would when they first came onto the scene.  You can't return to a list and automatically scroll down to where you were when you left it (unless I've missed something).  You can save the state of a Paged List and return to page x.

Comment: I've stand corrected, it 'kinda' works, I have a button that adds more entries to the list that the virtualizer uses. when the page loads, it doesn't initially work. but if I add more entries to the list, it will scroll down after clicking...most of the time, other times it scrolls to a different point. I'm still looking into it.